# Mysql - get sum() result in another column

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I get user_point column's sum like

```
select sum(user_point) as user_total_point from users;
```

but I also want to use that sum result for new generated column like

```
select sum(user_point) as user_total_point, (user_total_point * 100) as hundred_times from users;
```

-

```
Error: Query 1 ERROR: Unknown column 'user_total_point' in 'field list'
```

How can i use `user_total_point` column's value for another colums?

Answer (score 0):

If you want both values in the result, you can nest them as in:

```
select user_total_point, (user_total_point * 100) as hundred_times
from (
    select sum(user_point) as user_total_point
    from users
) as tmp;
```

Renaming ( `as user_total_point` ) happens last, so you can not reference that at the same level as you are defining it. The name does not exist yet when you reference it.